# Meteor 1.1 - Deploying with Neo4j database

Tags: meteor, neo4j

I have a network visualization app that uses Neo4j as its database. I would like to deploy this app with a Neo4j database, but I have never deployed a Meteor app with anything other than the default, MongoDB.

I would like to use GrapheneDB (http://www.graphenedb.com/). I have everything working locally using the Neo4j command line tool, but getting it to run while deployed is a different beast.

How do I deploy a Meteor app with Neo4j as its database?

Comment: [how about this](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-neo4j/blob/master/src/driver.coffee#L17)

Comment: Just saw on Twitter you answered your own question :) thanks for the blog post, maybe you can link it here as an answer for others.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Good call! I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a Meteor package that solves this. I wrote an article on Medium that takes you through the process if you find yourself in this position:

https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/connecting-meteor-to-a-neo4j-database-and-deploying-with-graphenedb-3321966c3102